# Issue while hitting a websocket api gateway route

Tags: amazon-web-services

Getting below error while deploying a websocket api gateway:

> `A route target (typically an Integration) must be defined for route with key $disconnect`

Does anyone knows the cause any resolution to the error?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a listener on the $disconnect route.
That's called an integration, and may be set up in the AWS console route details.

A simple lambda to catch the event may work:

[image: AWS console route details]